# How to update add/remove routes into Apache Camel under Spring Boot app in runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, routes, apache-camel

I need to add/remove `Apache Camel` routes at a runtime in `Spring Boot` application. It means that routes should be updated while application is running. It also means that I don't have all routes during the first run of the application and I cannot restart it in order to get them.

I found old answers but still cannot understand how to do it using `xml`-defined routes. Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: If you have jmx access coonfigured & working you can update routes via there while camel is running. Navigate to `org.apache.camel` and find your routes. do `dumpRoutesAsXml` to get your current list and see how its built, you can then call `updateRouteFromXml <string>` to load new routes on the fly. Tested with AMQ 5.16.0&Camel 2.25.2 let me know if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Put your xml under src/main/resources and invoke the following component :

```
    @Component 
    public class CamelRoutesLoader {

        @Autowired
        private CamelContext camelContext;

        @Value("${camel-routes-filename:#{null}}")
        private String routesFilename;

        @PostConstruct
        private void loadRoutes() {
            if(routesFilename == null) {
                //error no file name
            }
            try {
                InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(routesFilename).openStream();
                RoutesDefinition routes = ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(camelContext, is);
                camelContext.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //Impossible to load routes
            }
        }
    }
```

I call my component after it is initialized by Spring, but you can remove @PostConstruct, make it public and pass it the filename

Comment: Will it work if I dynamically will upload `xml` routes and would want to reload the whole camel context without an app restart?

Comment: Simply add and remove the routes as follows : `SpringCamelContext camel = applicationContext.getBean(SpringCamelContext.class);
List<RouteDefinition> routeDefinitions = camel.getRouteDefinitions();
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("extra-routes.xml").openStream();
RoutesDefinition routes2 = ModelHelper.loadRoutesDefinition(camel, is);
camel.addRouteDefinitions(routes2.getRoutes());
        
for (RouteDefinition routeDefinition : routeDefinitions) {
  camel.stopRoute(routeDefinition.getId());
  camel.removeRoute(routeDefinition.getId());
}`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add `camel.springboot.xml-routes-reload-directory=<monitoring-directory>` into `application.properties` and monitor routes into `xml` format.

It will reload all routes, so in order to add delete them, it possible to only add delete files with route definitions.

Comment: Just adding few notices for future readers. This feature is not intended for production use. It is used for development purposes only and was never enough stable for production use. It is deprecated in CAMEL 2.x and removed in Camel 3.0.0+  versions (See [CAMEL-13632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13632) for details)

Comment: @Bedla Is there any alternative to this?